# TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly SQLite3 Retrieving Data

Tags: python, sqlite

```
def course_id(enrolment_id):
    con = None

    try:
        con = lite.connect('C:/Users/Ethan/Desktop/SAT/SiemensAssessmentTool.db')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()

            cur.execute("SELECT course_id FROM Enrolment WHERE enrolment_id = '"+ enrolment_id+ "';")

            rows = cur.fetchall()
            courseids=[]
            for row in (rows):
                courseids = row
                return courseids

    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()
```

What I'm trying to do with this code is retrieve a number of integers, as I will be connecting it to another function to find other data from the database. The error I get is when I connect it with other function:

```
def course_name(course_id):
    con = None

    try:
        con = lite.connect('C:/Users/Ethan/Desktop/SAT/SiemensAssessmentTool.db')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()

            cur.execute("SELECT course_name FROM Course WHERE course_id = '"+ course_id+ "';")

            rows = cur.fetchall()

            return rows

    finally:
        if con:
            con.close()
```

And I get this error:

```
cur.execute("SELECT course_id FROM Enrolment WHERE enrolment_id = '"+ enrolment_id+ "';")
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the course_id function, but I am not sure.. Thank you in advance

Comment: is enrolement_id a list?

Answer (score 2):

> TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly

Clearly, the problem is that *`enrolment_id` is a list*, check what do you pass into the `course_id()` as an argument.

As a side note, you should not construct your query via string concatenation - this leads to problems with type conversions and makes your code vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - *parameterize the query* instead:

```
cur.execute("SELECT course_id FROM Enrolment WHERE enrolment_id = ?", (enrolment_id, ))
```

---

There is also a problem in how you get the result of the query. Assuming you want a single course ID from the database, use `fetchone()`:

```
courseid = cursor.fetchone()[0] 
return courseid
```

Comment: I have tried what you mentioned, and now I get the following error:sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Comment: @E.Lopez yeah, this sounds like the initial problem you have - what is the type of `enrolment_id` when you pass it into `course_id()` function?

Comment: It is meant to be an integer

Comment: @E.Lopez sure, but what is it in reality?

Comment: I am afraid I'm not sure what you mean. Could you rephrase that please? Sorry, I am not an expert in Python :P

Comment: @E.Lopez okay, let's debug that: put `print(enrolment_id, type(enrolment_id))` into the beginning of `course_id()` function and run the code - what do you see printed?

Comment: I get <class 'str'>, so I'm guessing it's a string?

Comment: @E.Lopez the problem is now related to how you get the course ID. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: I still get the error sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type. The code now looks like this:                   `def course_id(enrolment_id):
   
    con = None

    try:
        con = lite.connect('C:/Users/Ethan/Desktop/SAT/SiemensAssessmentTool.db')
        with con:
            cur = con.cursor()

            cur.execute("SELECT course_id FROM Enrolment WHERE enrolment_id = ?", [enrolment_id])            
            courseid = cur.fetchone()[0]
            return courseid
                
    finally:
        if con:
            con.close
`